IOS Restore in-app-subscription with backend server handling
In our application, users can log in with Google, Facebook, or a phone number. We have a subscription purchase system that is then recorded on the backend (including subscription start and end dates), so everything is managed server-side. If a user logs in on another device with the same account, they will still have access to their subscription.
Apple requires us to add a restore button.
If a user deletes their account in the app and then recreates it, we must give them the right to restore their subscription.
On the iOS side, we manage it like this:
Alter calling this function SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
         handleTransactions(transactions: transactions)
    
     }

    private func handleTransactions(transactions : [SKPaymentTransaction]){
 
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .restored:
            debugPrint("PaymentQueue: .restored")
            hasRestoredTransaction = true
            restore(transaction: transaction)
            break

This function  restore(transaction: transaction), calls the backend. If the backend responds with “OK,” the restoration is completed successfully.
Several issues arise:

For transaction in transactions, the number of transactions sometimes exceeds 100 (sandbox case), which puts too much load on the backend.

In the case of account deletion (meaning deletion on the backend as well) and account recreation, when we click on restore, the backend does not recognize the account.

If we are logged in with a different app account but the same Apple account, we are supposed to restore the purchase, even though the backend sees it as a new app account.


How can we manage the backend correctly with this restore button? Thank you for your help.

Why do you need to send all transactions to your server?  Surely it only needs the most recent? Even if you do want to send all 100+, there is no need to do so in 100 individual invocations. You can send them in batches You should use the originalTransactionIdentifier. If that identifier is associated with a different app account then you should move the subscription entitlement to the new app account.

I retrieved the app code, and it was like this. I’m asking what the best way to handle it is. I could identify the latest transaction by date, I suppose, and send just that one the last one no need to send the others ? Ok   I didn't quite understand the last paragraph  " Move   the subscription entitlement to the new app account "
Thank you for yours response

What I mean is your server should associate the original transaction identifier with your app user account. When you restore purchases, you have three possibilities: the original transaction id is associated with the account that is currently logged in, or the original id is associated with a different account or it is associated with no account. In the first case, nothing to do. In the second case, remove the association with the other account and associate it with the logged in account. Same in the third case; associate it with the logged in account.

i found the originalTransactionIdentifier  is now on the field transactions.original?.transactionIdentifier
